# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, raspberrypi, docker

Raspberry Pi 4 8GB

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

---

Before this happened, I was able to run a bunch of Docker containers without an issue. However, my Pi suddenly stopped working (wasn't able to SSH into it, wasn't able to launch Nextcloud or Jellyfin), so I decided to just do a soft shutdown. My Pi's case has a feature where if you hold the power button for 3 seconds, it does a soft shutdown.

When I powered it back on, none of my containers were running. I ran `docker container ls` to see if this was the case and I got:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Searched online, and people on StackOverflow saying I should do `sudo systemctl start docker`. Tried that but got:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So I ran `systemctl status docker.service` and it produced the following:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-04-04 12:50:28 EDT; 11s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 5618 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 5618 (code=exited, status=2)

Apr 04 12:50:26 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 04 12:50:26 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Apr 04 12:50:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Apr 04 12:50:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Apr 04 12:50:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 04 12:50:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 04 12:50:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Also ran `journalctl -xe` and got:

```
-- The job identifier is 2207 and the job result is done.
Apr 04 12:50:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.socket: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit docker.socket has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Apr 04 12:50:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: Closed Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit docker.socket has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A stop job for unit docker.socket has finished.
--
-- The job identifier is 2290 and the job result is done.
Apr 04 12:50:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit docker.socket has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A stop job for unit docker.socket has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 2290.
Apr 04 12:50:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.socket has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit docker.socket has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 2290.
Apr 04 12:50:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.socket has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit docker.socket has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 2290.
Apr 04 12:50:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 04 12:50:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit docker.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 04 12:50:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit docker.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 2207 and the job result is failed.
Apr 04 12:50:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit docker.socket has entered the 'failed' state with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
```

The info I was given didn't help me narrow anything down, so I kept searching and found someone else who told me to do `sudo dockerd`. That produced the following warnings:

```
INFO[2021-04-04T12:56:17.445820368-04:00] Starting up
INFO[2021-04-04T12:56:17.447780951-04:00] detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.           conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
INFO[2021-04-04T12:56:17.449789072-04:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-04T12:56:17.449890775-04:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-04T12:56:17.449956182-04:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containe           rd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-04T12:56:17.449991293-04:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-04T12:56:17.452504633-04:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-04T12:56:17.452582725-04:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-04T12:56:17.452640502-04:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containe           rd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-04T12:56:17.452674465-04:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2021-04-04T12:56:17.486909155-04:00] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2
WARN[2021-04-04T12:56:17.571738900-04:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup memory limit
WARN[2021-04-04T12:56:17.571820474-04:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period
WARN[2021-04-04T12:56:17.571848455-04:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime
WARN[2021-04-04T12:56:17.571874085-04:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight
WARN[2021-04-04T12:56:17.571899381-04:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device
INFO[2021-04-04T12:56:17.572419193-04:00] Loading containers: start.
```

So I'm thinking the issue must be related to my kernel. Did the soft shutdown somehow mess with the kernel? And how do I revert the issues so I can get Docker up and running again?